# Unable to install urllib.request on Python 3.5

Tags: python, request, urllib, python-module

I'm trying to install the urllib.request module but I get this error each time : 
*Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib*

How do I install urllib for Python 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the standard library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html

Comment: I tried running this code : 
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read() 

But terminal responds with this : 
File "Check.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request